# Waves speed and particle speed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

Is the speed of a wave the same as the speed of the particle it displaces? Homework question,any help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you should look up wikipedia or something similar to find out what you can about waves and then put more in your question if you have not worked out the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. The particles of the medium in which the wave is travelling (assuming that this is a mechanical wave) aren't actually displaced in the direction of the wave, but are merely disturbed. In the case of a longitudinal wave (e.g. sound), a particle will for a time be moving in the direction of propagation the wave, for a time be at rest and for a time be moving opposite to the direction of propagation of the wave, and the maximum speed it attains has to do with the amplitude, not the speed of propagation of the wave. In the case of a transverse wave (e.g. waves formed on a string when you move an end up and down), the aswer to your question becomes even more readily apparent - the particles don't even move in the direction of propagation of the wave, but rather in a direction perpendicular to propagation and so there's no reason to expect them to be moving at the same speed as the wave.

Comment: Nice answer, but you say "transverse wave (e.g. waves on a spring)": intuitively I rather think of longitudinal waves on a spring. Maybe a string is a better example to avoid confusion. Another example is a wave in water: the particles don't go forward or backward, they just go up and down.

Comment: @David Could you provide some reference where it says that water waves do not move forward and backward but only up and down?

Comment: @isopycnal try this. Pour some water in a bucket or something and place a floating object on it. Wait for the water to be stagnant and no wind and disturb the water to create ripples. Your result will answer your question.

Comment: @David Thanks for the suggestion. I edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @IsopycnalOscillation What David (I presume) means is that normal water waves (of the sort you see on the surface of the ocean, or when you drop a rubber ducky in a bathtub) are transverse waves, and you can see that this is the case by simply observing the surface of the water as the wave propagates. That is not to say that longitudinal waves cannot form in water: sound propagates under water, and this would be an example of a longitudinal wave in water.